# How to use vue-select with b-pagination?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, v-select, vue-select

I'm trying to work with pagination using the v-pagination component from bootstrap-vue. It's working more or less as I want, however when I click on a certain page the component is closing.

[image: Component is closing before selecting the option]

I would like to know how I can prevent v-select from closing before I select one of the options.

My code:

```
<v-select
    id="municipio"
    v-model="municipioState"
    :options="municipiosPaginaAtual"
    :filterable="false"
    placeholder="Selecione seu município"
    label="municipio"
    @search="buscarMunicipio"
>
  <div slot="no-options">
    Selecione o Estado!
  </div>
  <li
    slot="list-footer"
    class="pagination"
    @click.prevent=""
  >
    <b-pagination
      v-model="municipioPaginacao"
      :total-rows="municipiosFiltradosQuantidade"
      :per-page="limit"
      first-number
      last-number
    />
  </li>
</v-select>
```

If there is a workaround or other option than v-select I would be pleased to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `@mouseup.native.capture.stop` in the `b-pagination` tag to prevent closing the dropdown of the `vue-select`.
Also, in my opinion, you can use `vue-multiselect` for a better user experience, but it's up to you and your need. I just wanted to suggest it to you as another option.
I provided a simple snippet to show this:

```js
Vue.component("v-select", VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      books: [{
          title: "Old Man's War"
        },
        {
          title: "The Lock Artist"
        },
        {
          title: "HTML5"
        },
        {
          title: "Right Ho Jeeves"
        },
        {
          title: "The Code of the Wooster"
        },
        {
          title: "Thank You Jeeves"
        }
      ],
      perPage: 2,
      currentPage: 1,
      rows: 6
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@3.16.0/dist/vue-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@3.16.0/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <v-select :options="books" label="title">
    <li slot="list-footer">
      <b-pagination @mouseup.native.capture.stop v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage"></b-pagination>
    </li>
  </v-select>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful! It was really the answer I was looking for. It worked with b-pagination and I will try vue-multiselect too!